# How to do implement a paging solution with a dict object in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, paging

Is there a better way to implement a paging solution using `dict` than this?

I have a `dict` with image names and URLs.
I need to 16 key value pairs at a time depending on the user's request, i.e. page number.
It's a kind of paging solution.
I can implement this like:

For example :

```
dict = {'g1':'first', 'g2':'second', ... }
```

Now I can create a mapping of the keys to numbers using:

```
ordered={}

for i, j in enumerate(dict):
    ordered[i]=j
```

And then retrieve them:

```
dicttosent={}

for i in range(paegnumber, pagenumber+16):
  dicttosent[ordered[i]] = dict[ordered[i]]
```

Is this a proper method, or will this give random results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Store *g1*, *g2*, etc in a list called *imagelist*
- Fetch the pages using `imagelist[pagenumber: pagenumber+16]`.
- Use your original dict (image numbers to urls) to lookup the url for each of those 16 imagenames.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1) Will this give random results ?

Sort of.

Quoting from the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) about `dict`:

> Keys and values are iterated over in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

So for your purposes you can't know a priori on what will be the order of your iteration.

[`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is what you're looking for: *an OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted.*

#### 2) Is this actually a proper method?

It doesn't seem so.

I don't know if there are library that will handle all that information for you (maybe someone else can tell you that), but it seems like you're trying to emulate the `OrderedDict` behaviour.

You can directly use an `OrderedDict`, or if you want to enumerate your info a `list` can do that.

Comment: Django, being a web framework, has a facility called [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) that deals with this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If your `dict` doesn't change during the lifetime of the application and you don't care about ordering of the items in your dict you should be ok.

If not, you should probably use `collections.OrderedDict` or keep a sorted list of keys, depending on your requirements. Using normal `dict` doesn't give you any guarantees about iteration order, so after each modification of the input dict you can get different results.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a `dict` that maps to your pages? You could start off with two lists, one containing your image names and the other containing the URLs.

```
perPage = 16
nameList = ['g1', 'g2', ... ]
urlList = ['first', 'second', ... ]

# This is a generator expression that can create
# the nested dicts. You can also use a simple
# for loop
pageDict = dict(( (i, dict(( (nameList[j], urlList[j]) 
    for j in range(i*perPage, i*perPage+perPage))))
    for i in range(len(nameList) / perPage)))
```

It indexes from `0`, so your first page will be `pageDict[0]`.

...Now that I look at it again, that generator expression looks kind of awful. :|